# Php “preview” and “next”

Tags: php, pagination

I have a code what generated a list for number of pages, but I want to replace them with two buttons “preview” and “next”

Code is:

```
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records

//break total records into pages
$pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);   

//create pagination
if($pages > 1)
{
    $pagination = '';
    $pagination .= '<ul class="paginate">';
    for($i = 1; $i<$pages; $i++)
    {
        $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
    $pagination .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a var to know the current page, like:

```
$page = ($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

if($pages > 1)
{
    $pagination = '';
    $pagination .= '<ul class="paginate">';
    $pagination .= '<li><a href="file.php?page='.($page-1).'" class="paginate_click" id="prev-page">previous</a></li>';
    for($i = 1; $i<$pages; $i++)
    {
        $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
    $pagination .= '<li><a href="file.php?page='.($page+1).'" class="paginate_click" id="next-page">next</a></li>';
    $pagination .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: If you want to replace the pages numbers, just remove the whole content of for{...}

Comment: Oh sure, using filter_var() is way better than only int(). Just remember to change (in the filter) $_POST to $_GET if you do it like my example.

Answer (score 1):

I would use current page with php get but if you are doing where javascript is progressing the pages here is an example.

You will have to modify since I can not see the javascript you are using

You can use jquery

```
<?php

$results        = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records

//break total records into pages
$pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);   

?>

<ul class="paginate">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var hash = $(location).attr('hash');
      hash = hash.substring(1, hash.length); // Remove #

  var pages = <?php echo $pages; ?>;

  var content = '';

  if(hash > 1 && hash <= pages)
  content += '<li><a href="http://test.com/index.php#' + (hash - 1) + '" class="paginate_click" id="' + (hash - 1) + '-page">previous</a></li>';

if(hash >= 1 && hash < pages)
  content += '<li><a href="http://test.com/index.php#' + (hash + 1) + '" class="paginate_click" id="' + (hash + 1) + '-page">next</a></li>';

  $('.paginate').html(content);

});
</script> 
</ul>
```